# PCA threshold tuning in Caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, r-caret

I am trying to build a classifier from some data using caret.
One of the approaches I want to try is a simple LDA from data pre-processed with PCA.
I found out how to use caret for this:

```
fitControl <- trainControl("repeatedcv", number=10, repeats = 10,
                                preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.9))
ldaFit1 <- train(label ~ ., data = tab,
                method = "lda2",
                preProcess = c("center", "scale", "pca"),
                trControl = fitControl)
```

As expected caret is comparing the accuracy of the LDA with different dimensions values:

```
Linear Discriminant Analysis

 158 samples
1955 predictors
   3 classes: '1', '2', '3'

Pre-processing: centered (1955), scaled (1955), principal component
 signal extraction (1955)
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times)
Summary of sample sizes: 142, 142, 143, 142, 143, 142, ...
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  dimen  Accuracy   Kappa
  1      0.5498987  0.1151681
  2      0.5451340  0.1298590

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was dimen = 1.
```

What I would like to do is to add the PCA threshold to the tuning parameters, however I cannot find a way to do this.

Is there a simple solution for this with caret? Or does one need to repeat the training step with different pre-processing options and select the best value in the end?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452615/r-caret-how-do-i-apply-separate-pca-to-different-dataframes-before-training/59480195#59480195 it contains an answer to a more complex question however the answer contains how to achieve the desired tuning of retained PCA components  using mlr3 package. If you are fond of caret check this option using recipes: https://www.r-bloggers.com/tuning-a-data-preprocessing-pipeline-with-recipes-and-modelgrid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the links pointed out by missuse I managed to integrate the variance explained threshold of PCA to the parameter tuning:

```
library(caret)
library(recipes)
library(MASS)

# Setting up a vector of thresholds to try out
pca_varex <- c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.995, 0.999)

# Setting up recipe
initial_recipe <- recipe(train, formula = label ~ .) %>%
                    step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
                    step_scale(all_predictors())

# Define the modelgrid
models <- model_grid() %>%
            share_settings(data = train,
                            trControl = caret::trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                                        number = 10,
                                                        repeats = 10),
                            method = "lda2") 

# Add models with different PCA thresholds
for (i in pca_varex) {
    models <- models %>% add_model(model_name = sprintf("varex_%s", i),
                                    x = initial_recipe %>%
                                        step_pca(all_predictors(), threshold = i))
}

# Train
models <- models %>% train(.)
```

Though looking up the modelgrid and recipes documentation the tidymodels package may be the most straightforward way (https://www.tidymodels.org/).